# Create a subscriber to an Image topic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, camera, image, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Im trying to wrtie a node that subscribes to a image topic, however, after almost copying the ros tutorial, I keep getting an error.
The relevant parts of my code are:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
image_transport::Subscriber sub;
sub=it.subscribe("/sensors/camera/top/image_raw",1, Imtest::callbackSubscriber);
```

And my callback is:

```
void Imtest::callbackSubscriber(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
```

The error I get is:

```
/home/kal3-5/workspaces/my_first_ws/src/imtest_ros_tool/src/imtest/imtest.cpp:41:83: error: invalid use of non-static member function
     sub=it.subscribe("/sensors/camera/top/image_raw",1, Imtest::callbackSubscriber);
```

My version of ROS is Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290728/create-a-subscriber-to-an-image-topic/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here is at the subscriber attribution, you must pass a function pointer to it using the '&' before the method name.
If you replace the subscriber attribution line for the following, it may solves your problem:

```
sub=it.subscribe("/sensors/camera/top/image_raw",1, &Imtest::callbackSubscriber, this);
```

Waiting for reply.

---

Originally posted by [matheusns](https://answers.ros.org/users/29215/matheusns/) with karma: 111 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-09**:
In c++ a function name without parentheses () decomposes to a function pointer, there is no need for the & operator. The problem the OP is having is caused because they are trying to use a method of a class without a pointer to the instance of that class.

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2018-05-10**:
It was really funny, because a tried this solution at first, and it didnt work, but when I write the new node to show you guys the error, it worked!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The difference between your code and the example tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages) is that the tutorial is using a plain function as the callback handler, where you are trying to use a class method. Therefore to call the callback method ROS needs to know the method to call and a pointer to an instance of the object.

Now there are two ways you can use a class method as a callback function:

1. Make the method static so that no object pointer is needed to call it. This may not be appropriate in your case.
2. Subscribe to the camera topic using a ptr to the object instance that you want to receive the callback AND a pointer to the method within that object that will actually handle the callback. Here is a code snippet of this:

   // instance of the imtest object to handle image callbacks.
   Imtest imtestInstance;

   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
   image_transport::Subscriber sub;

   // Subscribe to the topic using instance pointer and method pointer.
   sub=it.subscribe("/sensors/camera/top/image_raw",1, Imtest::callbackSubscriber, &imtestInstance);

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1